# how to create a dynamical collection on Mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i mean how to create a dynamical collection on Mongodb using node js, (equivalent to add column with a name chosen by user on Mysql).

Comment: Can you show your data structure and expected data structure? Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: @titi23 
sorry for the late response, i mean on my question if there is a method to create a collection on Mongodb with a name chosen in an input and all the variables on this collection should be entered in an input.